# locationManager updates

Tags: android, location

So I have the following code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
  }

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1 locationListener);
```

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

But the thing is I want to call `makeUseOfNewLocation(location);` every 1 meter, I walked through my house(with my internet from the provider ON) and still did not manage to get in `makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location)`.

I am using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` because the time for request does not matter.

How can I fix the problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter where you have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is where you put in the distance.

See the documentation for LocationManager at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent)

`1f` instead of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` should do it, provided everything else is OK.

**Edit** Actually, check the documentation.  Looks like your call there is more than a bit inaccurate (for what you are trying to do -- looks like wrong version of the function).

**Edit #2** Based on your reply, you have set infinity as the minimum time between updates.  Try `0f`.  Also, for the minDistance, try `1f` instead of 1 to ensure it is a float.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but actually I am using:
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener) Where the 2nd parameter is time :) Wrong version?

Comment: Updated based on your response.

Comment: Thank you again! You're right the minimum time is almost infinity yes but if I do walk 1 meter it requests an update(I think!) By the way I tried already with 1f and still nothing :(

Comment: Similar code works for me, so try it out.  Also, if this answers your question, be sure to accept it by clicking the checkmark.